# в чем ошибка? хочу чтобы выводило x 3 раза если условие верно

Tags: python

```
x = input()
if x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 == 0:
    print(x)
    print(x)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Функция `input()` всегда возвращает строку. Операция `%` применительно к строке выполняет подстановку указанного значения внутрь строки и возвращает тоже строку. Затем вы пытаетесь сравнить эту строку с числом 0, и это условие всегда будет ложно, потому что никакая строка никогда не бывает равна никакому числу

Answer (score 1):

`input()` всегда возвращает строку. Преобразуйте ввод в число используя `int(S)`:

```py
x = int(input())
if x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 == 0:
    print(x)
    print(x)
    print(x)
```